Creating a Realistic 3D Clothing Model with Fabric Physics for Interaction in Apple Vision Pro
How can I create a 3D model of clothing that behaves like real fabric, with realistic physics? Is it possible to achieve this model by photogrammetry? I want to use this model in the Apple Vision Pro and interact with it using hand gestures.
I can load a model and move it with pinching, but I don't know how to find a realistic fabric model and how to treat it.

I looked into this for a bit trying to make paper and the only solutions I found were with Blender. You might be able to add the material from a photogrammetry model later but the fabric physics won't come from a basic 3D model.

Soft body dynamics in RealityKit 4.0
You can definitely create a 3D model that looks like real-world fabric using photogrammetry tool, but at the moment, it's almost impossible to simulate fabric physics based on the RealityKit engine, especially for Vision Pro (with a frame rate of 90 fps). To work with realistic soft bodies, you'll need a special software solver capable of calculating the plausible physics of a virtual fabric consisting of several thousand polygons in real time. The Unreal and Unity engines can do a fabric simulation, but it's rather a low-quality simulation of character clothing.
Possible solution
You can use baked nCloth simulation (to play it as an animation in a RealityKit 4.0 scene), but without interacting with fabric object. To create an animated cloth, use Autodesk Maya or SideFX Houdini authoring software.
